# How can I read a String from a file split it into characters and put it in to a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a program that simulates the function of a scantron marker. I have a text file with the name of the student follow by their answers. Here's the sample file I created:

```
Arnie
EADCC
Betty
dadec
Carol
ba ea
```

In my main I ask the user to input the file name and I pass that to a QuizMarker class that I created. Now I want to grab the name as a string and put it into a 1D array and grab the answers as a character array and put it into a 2D array so that I can compare the Student answers with a correct answers file. I hard coded the number of rows just for testing purposes. I have been trying to figure out how to make this work the whole freaking day but my brain is completely toasted by now. I need HELP. here is my code for the method `readNamesAnswers():`

```
public void readNamesAnswers(){
    while (readerStu_Ans.hasNext()){
        studentName[indexStudentName] = readerStu_Ans.nextLine();
        for (int iRowStudentAnswer=0; iRowStudentAnswer<3; iRowStudentAnswer++){
             studentAnswers[iRowStudentAnswer]= stuAnswers.split("(?!^)");
             System.out.println(studentAnswers[iRowStudentAnswer][0]);
        }

        for(int row=0; row<3; row++){
            for(int column= 0; column<studentAnswers[column].length; column++){
                  System.out.println(studentAnswers[column][row]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n"+studentName[indexStudentName]);
        System.out.println();
        indexStudentName++;
    }
}
```

PS. I new to Java and programming in general.

Answer (score 1):

You created very complicated code which is hard to understand and hard to maintain.
Do you really need to use 2 dimensional array?

This could be done easly another way. You could create another class which holds all data for each student. Something like this.

```
public class Student{

        private String name;
        private String answer;

        public Student(String name, String answer) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.answer = answer;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getAnswer() {
            return answer;
        }

        public void setAnswer(String answer) {
            this.answer = answer;
        }
```

}

By having this class you can easly set and get any information for each student.

You can read a file line by line and add information of each student in a new instance of Student.
Each student is a new instance of Student.

You can keep all those objects in a List, Set, Map or something... Read about [collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) in Java. It's very important.

Here is one way of doing it.

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

int studentCount = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++) {    
    students.add(new Student("name", "answer"));
}
```

This way, the code is easy to read and easy to understand.
Once you learn collections, you'll ask yourself how could you even program without it... you'll reborn!

Comment: +1 Excellent answer. Congratulations on posting the highest quality/reputation (currently just 6) ratio I've ever seen.

Comment: Nice answer! Well, if you want answer to be in char[] you can use "ABCD".toCharArray() to convert string to char[]

Comment: You answer is superb.However I do kinda have to use 2D arrays and not arrayLists. Its for an assignment for University that i'm working on. I understand what I have to do but i guess its just not my day. I know i have to read the data as a string split it into characters maybe by using chartAt()?? so that then I can load it into the 2D array. And trust me I tried all afternoon, did research all over the internet but for some reason im still doing something wrong and I have no clue what it is.. the code that I posted was just me desperately trying to make "something work".